# How to change content of div on hover using JQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to change the contents of a div when it's hovered over using JQuery. I've seen answers on stack overflow, but I can't seem to get it working.

I've tried

```
$( "imgDiv" ).mouseover(
    function() {
        $("tdiv").textContent = "hovering";
    }, 
    function() {
        $("tdiv").textContent = 'title';
    }
);
```

I've also replaced "mouseover" with "hover". I've used a variable and the actual div in place of "imgDiv".

This is what my code looks like:

```js
imgDiv = document.getElementById('imgDiv');
tDiv = document.getElementById('titleDiv');


$( "imgDiv" ).mouseover(
     function() {
         $("tdiv").textContent = "hovering";
     }, function() {
       $("tdiv").textContent = 'title';
     }
   );
```

```css
body {
  background: white;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
#imgDiv {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="imgDiv">

<div id=titleDiv>title</div>

</div>
```

Comment: `tdiv` is not a valid selector.  `<tdiv>` isn't a thing

Comment: You're trying to stick variables in quotes.  Remove the quotes.

Comment: Also `jQuery` does not expose `textContent`.  Use `text(newvalue)` instead.

Comment: jQuery uses `.text()` or `.html()`

Comment: This is basically littered with basic errors, so go back to the *answers on stack overflow* and read them more carefully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery's `.hover()` function along with the `.text()` function to do what you want. Also, no need for `document.getElementById`:

```js
$("#imgDiv").hover(
  function() {
    $("#titleDiv").text("hovering");
  },
  function() {
    $("#titleDiv").text('title');
  }
);
```

```css
body {
  background: white;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#imgDiv {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="imgDiv">
  <div id="titleDiv">title</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can target the div with jQuery, and store it's original value.  On mouseout, you can restore it.  Also using mouseenter reduces the number of times the logic processes as mouseover will fire for every mouse move over the element.

```js
var $titleDiv = $('#titleDiv');

$("#imgDiv")
  .on('mouseenter', function() {
    $titleDiv.data('originalText', $titleDiv.text());
    $titleDiv.text('hovering');
  })
  .on('mouseout', function() {
    $titleDiv.text($titleDiv.data('originalText'));
  });
```

```css
body {
  background: white;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#imgDiv {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="imgDiv">

  <div id="titleDiv">title</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, replace `$("imgDiv")` with `$("#imgDiv")` to get the element with id (#) `imgDiv`.

Then  `$("tdiv")` doesn't exist, you probably mean  `$("div")` to select a `<div>`tag in your DOM.

And finally, $("tdiv").textContent doesn't exist. You can try `$("div").html()` or `$("div").text()` to get the `<div>` tag content

--

Quick reminder : [jQuery documentation on selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/basic-css-selectors/)

`$("div")` will select the `<div>` tags

`$(".element")` will select tags with `class="element"`

`$("#element")` will select tags with `id="element"`

Answer (score 0):

You need to try like this

```js
$( "#imgDiv" ).mouseover(function() {
         $("#titleDiv").text("hovering");
     }).mouseleave( function() {
       $("#titleDiv").text('title');
     });
```

```css
body {
  background: white;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
#imgDiv {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="imgDiv">

<div id=titleDiv>title</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution,

```js
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
function out() {
 s[0].innerHTML = 'hello';
}

function ibn() {
 s[0].innerHTML = 'Myname';
}
```

```html
<div onmouseout = 'out()' onmouseenter = 'ibn()'> Myname </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call reference a dom with pure Javascript and them manipulate it with jQuery - it will not work.

Try this:

```
$( "#imgDiv" ).mouseover(function() {
      $("#titleDiv").text("hovering");     
});
```

The `titleDiv` id has to be referenced in your code using "#", then the id name.

Also, use `$("#name_of_id").text("your content")` instead of `.textContent()`

Comment: Instead of just giving a code answer, also try and explain why this would work and how.